# Codeigniter 4 cache writing error occured

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

i am using new version of CI which is 4 .

I am seeing below error when I load my project on the server.

```
Cache unable to write to /var/www/html/blank/writable/cache/
```

I give right and permission to writable folder as well but it is not resolving this issue. My project is setup in centos.

Comment: Are you giving the rights to the server user (most likely www-data) ?

Comment: Refer to the link : https://linuxize.com/post/linux-chown-command/  Most probably apache2 uses www-data as a user name and user group.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very frequent issue in codeigniter4.

here is the answer.

You need to set permission for the main folder with below command.

```
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t {path_of_your_project_directory} -R
```

Thanks ..